# Command Line Folder Comparison that outputs difference

Tags: windows

I'm looking for a Windows command line utility that outputs the differences of two folders into another folder.

An example, I have folder A which has already been deployed, I want to deploy folder B, which is a updated version of folder A. So I need a list of the changes I need to make in order to make Folder A match folder B.

Answer (score 1):

[Beyond Compare](http://www.scootersoftware.com) has some command line abilities although I can't find much on their website about them.

They are fully documented in the help file and you can download a fully functional trial version.

Answer (score 0):

[rsync](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync) will sync up two folders. there are implementations of it on windows, e.g. as part of [cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/)

Comment: `rsync` will sync but it won't just tell you about the differences.

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend [unison](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison) for syncing directories (local or remote). There is a nice graphical GTK client, but the command line version is always available.

> Unison is a file-synchronization tool
>   for Unix and Windows. It allows two
>   replicas of a collection of files and
>   directories to be stored on different
>   hosts (or different disks on the same
>   host), modified separately, and then
>   brought up to date by propagating the
>   changes in each replica to the other.

Answer (score 0):

Something like [WinMerge](http://winmerge.org/) will let you see the differences between one folder and another, and will let you apply changes to one or the other.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I find the `diff.exe` that comes with [Vim](http://www.vim.org/) to be useful.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why no one answer with the better free comparision tool in the market,

> Total Commander

(http://www.ghisler.com/)

Even you compare with any method, byte, CRC, date, etc. and move from one to another site.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

The answer is simple:

```
comp path1\* path2\*
```

Comment: Well, you could give an example output, explain how to open the command line, things like this.

Comment: This answer compares the folders, but it doesn't **do anything** with the results, so it doesn't really answer the question.